# The meaning of the phrase "set-up" in context

Tags: meaning

I have looked up all the meaning of the phrase in various dictionaries, but still cannot get what it means in the second sentence . Here it goes:

> Religion is a social institution that involves a unified system of beliefs and practices and recognizes the sacred. But this is not **a set-up** between good and evil.

Comment: Please, always add the source if you didn't write it.

Comment: Perhaps [*set-up*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/set-up): "9. to advance or propose (a theory, etc.)" I don't think the usage as a noun is appropriate without context, because we have no idea what the *set-up* might be. See "1. *countable noun* - A particular set-up is a particular system or way of organizing something."

Answer (score 0):

In context, this likely means that religions are not created in order to fight for good and against evil. In certain cases, we can use, "Set-up" to describe the creation of a conflict between two people or powers (good and evil), or a trick that gets two powers to fight.